# comma separated string to sequence

Tags: freemarker

I have comma separated string, e.g. apple, banana, mango. I want to loop over it or I want to convert it in freemarker sequence so I can loop on it. Next I want to show only the first two value, e.g. apple and banana only. Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried till now

Comment: is there anything to try ? i have sting apple,banana,mango just want to convert it as array sequence so i can loop over it .. i cant try until i dnt convert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact syntax is (like what if an item contains comma), also perhaps the parsing shouldn't be the concern of the template (what's the use case?). But something like `words?split(r"\s*,\s*", "r")[0..*2]` will give you the list of the first at-most-two value.

Comment: let me try this be back here soon . i just want first two word nothing else.

Comment: but want single single so can perform different operation on each

Comment: it will retrun me as array or just as string because i dont want it as string

Comment: `words?split(r"\s*,\s*", "r")` returns an array (an FTL sequence in fact, but never mind). So you can query its size (via `?size`), get individual items from it (via `[index]`), `#list` it, etc. BTW, you can easily try things out at http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/.

Comment: thanks but one more question please can you make me understand what these properties doing.

Comment: var?split(r"\s*,\s*", "r")[0..*2]

var?stplit is spiliting it and [0..*2]  shoing only 0 to 2 index value bt what is (r"\s*,\s*", "r")  doing